# When will onCompletion be launched in MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

I try to use the following code to play music.
I know I need to release `mediaPlayer` as soon as possible if I don't use it again, so I place the release code in `onCompletion`.

1: Will `onCompletion` be launched after a music have finished play?

2: Will `onCompletion` be launched after I invoke `mediaPlayer?.stop()`?

3: Will `onCompletion` be launched if the Activity which invoke `PlayHelper` is destroied?

**Code**

```
class PlayHelper  private constructor():  MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    fun play(path: String){
        mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer()

        mediaPlayer?.setAudioAttributes(
            AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build()
        )

        mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(path)
        mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener(this@PlayHelper)
        mediaPlayer?.prepareAsync()
    }


    fun pause(){
        mediaPlayer?.pause()
    }

    fun stop(){
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
    }

    
    /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
    override fun onPrepared(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }

    override fun onCompletion(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile private var instance: PlayHelper? = null

        fun getInstance() = instance?: synchronized(this) {
            instance?: PlayHelper().also { instance = it }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the [official documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener#onCompletion(android.media.MediaPlayer)), `onCompletion` is called only when the end of a media source is reached during playback. So, in other cases, like calling `mediaPlayer.stop()`, it won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

> 1: Will onCompletion be launched after a music have finished play?

It will.

> 2: Will onCompletion be launched after I invoke mediaPlayer?.stop()?

It will not.

> 3: Will onCompletion be launched if the Activity which invoke PlayHelper is destroied?

It will not. The PlayHelper will be removed from memory when the Activity is destroyed.

This link: [onCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) from the docs contains the following line:

> Called when the end of a media source is reached during playback.